# Calculate the difference between max and min values of two vectors for nested subsets of those vectors

Tags: r, loops, nested

I have a dataframe of about 900 rows (see simplified sample below). I am trying to estimate the value of the maximum(doy) – minimum(doy) per whaleID, per year. I need to return an object (e.g. table) of the doy difference by whaleID and year. One challenge is that not every year contains two 'doy' observations. I’ve tried using “dplyr”, aggregate() and making a loop (which I am not yet competent in designing). I’d like to achieve this using Base if possible, but am all ears for any suggestions for help on this one, thank you!

```
whaleID<-c(31,4,5,65,31,4,4,4,31,5)
year<-c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011)
doy<-c(65,71,88,67,77,78,81,82,88,88)
```

Comment: I n case there is only one row for `doy` how do you want to calculate the difference? Should it be 0 or the same single value ? Can you show the expected output for given data ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `aggregate()` and subtract the values from `range()`:

```
whaleID<-c(31,4,5,65,31,4,4,4,31,5)
year<-c(2010, 2010, 2010, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011, 2011)
doy<-c(65,71,88,67,77,78,81,82,88,88)
dfx <- data.frame(whaleID, year, doy)
aggregate(dfx$doy, by = list(whaleId = dfx$whaleID, year = dfx$year),
          FUN = function(x) diff(range(x)))

  whaleId year  x
1       4 2010  0
2       5 2010  0
3      31 2010  0
4       4 2011  4
5       5 2011  0
6      31 2011 11
7      65 2011  0
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am missing something but isn't this `aggregate(doy~whaleID + year, df, function(x) diff(range(x)))` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, that is equivalent. I like the `by` syntax vs. formula syntax personally, but I guess that's a matter of style. `diff(range(x))` I think is an improvement, will update to that choice